# Visual Studio 2015 RC Outlook reference

Tags: office-interop, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to add the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` reference to a project in Visual Studio 2015 RC. But it doesn't appear in my current installed references. I've found some additional installers for Office Developer tools, but these all require Visual Studio 2013 or lower. Has the installer for Visual Studio 2015 been released yet? Or is there any other way to send an e-mail via Outlook in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: It has been obsolete for the past 5 years, replaced by the Embed Interop Types feature.   Select the reference from the COM tab instead, pick "Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library".

Comment: @HansPassant That's exactly the reference I was looking for, but as I mentioned. It does not appear.

Comment: Hmm, you only mentioned the PIA, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.  PIAs are obsolete.  The COM type library has a different name, check the comment again.

Comment: @HansPassant It's not there. Like i said.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after a search I found the below link:

[Latest Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/11/23/latest-microsoft-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2015/)

I clicked and installed

> 2. Go grab the latest version with aka.ms/GetLatestOfficeDevTools.

Now I can see

> Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library

Hope it helps.